# Unable to Connect Ignitevisor to running cluster

Tags: java, kubernetes, ignite

I am encountering the following error while trying to connect the ignitevisor to a running cluster.

The server is running in a pod inside Kubernetes and I attempted to launch ignitevisor in the pod using a copy of the client configuration.

This procedure has worked for me in the past, not sure what the issue is now.

I checked the Ignite sever and there are no errors there.

Ignitevisor error:

```
Choose configuration file number ('c' to cancel) [0]: 9

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Using configuration | /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config/igniteServer.xml |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Nov 29, 2022 3:13:09 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config/igniteServer.xml]
Nov 29, 2022 3:13:09 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@694abbdc: startup date [Tue Nov 29 15:13:09 GMT 2022]; root of context hierarchy
[15:13:09]    __________  ________________ 
[15:13:09]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/
[15:13:09]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/
[15:13:09] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/
[15:13:09]
[15:13:09] ver. 2.11.1#20211220-sha1:eae1147d
[15:13:09] 2021 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
[15:13:09]
[15:13:09] Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org
[15:13:09]
[15:13:09] Quiet mode.
[15:13:09]   ^-- Logging to file '/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/work/log/ignite-ab6254d9.0.log'
[15:13:09]   ^-- Logging by 'JavaLogger [quiet=true, config=null]'
[15:13:09]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
[15:13:09]
[15:13:09] OS: Linux 5.15.0-53-generic amd64
[15:13:09] VM information: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_212-b04 IcedTea OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.212-b04
[15:13:09] Please set system property '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true' to avoid possible problems in mixed environments.
[15:13:09] Configured plugins:
[15:13:09]   ^-- None
[15:13:09]
[15:13:09] Configured failure handler: [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]]]
[15:13:09] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
[15:13:10] Security status [authentication=off, sandbox=off, tls/ssl=off]
[15:13:24,636][SEVERE][tcp-client-disco-sock-writer-#2%igniteClientInstance%-#35%igniteClientInstance%][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to send message: null
java.io.IOException: Failed to get acknowledge for message: TcpDiscoveryClientMetricsUpdateMessage [super=TcpDiscoveryAbstractMessage [sndNodeId=null, id=973f2f3c481-ab6254d9-a0e1-4ad2-b361-90238c290126, verifierNodeId=null, topVer=0, pendingIdx=0, failedNodes=null, isClient=true]]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$SocketWriter.body(ClientImpl.java:1491)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:58)
[15:14:05,899][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal%igniteClientInstance] Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=o.a.i.i.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, addressFilter=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=org.apache.ignite.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@4912d525], reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, soLinger=0, forceSrvMo
de=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null, skipAddrsRandomization=false]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:281)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:980)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1985)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1331)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2141)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1787)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1172)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:668)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:590)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:328)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.open.VisorOpenCommand.open(VisorOpenCommand.scala:251)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.open.VisorOpenCommand.open(VisorOpenCommand.scala:218)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.open.VisorOpenCommand.open(VisorOpenCommand.scala:94)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.open.VisorOpenCommand$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(VisorOpenCommand.scala:305)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole.mainLoop(VisorConsole.scala:237)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole$.delayedEndpoint$org$apache$ignite$visor$commands$VisorConsole$1(VisorConsole.scala:358)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole$delayedInit$body.apply(VisorConsole.scala:347)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole$.main(VisorConsole.scala:347)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole.main(VisorConsole.scala)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to connect to cluster, connection failed and failed to reconnect.
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$Reconnector.body(ClientImpl.java:1711)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:58)
[15:14:05,901][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal%igniteClientInstance] Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine).
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1990)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1331)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2141)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1787)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1172)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:668)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:590)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:328)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.open.VisorOpenCommand.open(VisorOpenCommand.scala:251)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.open.VisorOpenCommand.open(VisorOpenCommand.scala:218)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.open.VisorOpenCommand.open(VisorOpenCommand.scala:94)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.open.VisorOpenCommand$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(VisorOpenCommand.scala:305)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole.mainLoop(VisorConsole.scala:237)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole$.delayedEndpoint$org$apache$ignite$visor$commands$VisorConsole$1(VisorConsole.scala:358)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole$delayedInit$body.apply(VisorConsole.scala:347)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole$.main(VisorConsole.scala:347)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole.main(VisorConsole.scala)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, addressFilter=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=org.apache.ignite.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@4912d525], reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, soLinger=0,
 forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null, skipAddrsRandomization=false]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:281)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:980)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1985)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to connect to cluster, connection failed and failed to reconnect.
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$Reconnector.body(ClientImpl.java:1711)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:58)
[15:14:05] Ignite node stopped OK [name=igniteClientInstance, uptime=00:01:03.405]
[WARN ] Type 'help open' to see how to use this command.
+-------------------------------------+
| Status               | Disconnected |
| Ignite instance name | <n/a>        |
| Config path          | <n/a>        |
| Uptime               | <n/a>        |
+-------------------------------------+
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:1098)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:331)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.open.VisorOpenCommand.open(VisorOpenCommand.scala:251)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.open.VisorOpenCommand.open(VisorOpenCommand.scala:218)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.open.VisorOpenCommand.open(VisorOpenCommand.scala:94)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.open.VisorOpenCommand$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(VisorOpenCommand.scala:305)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole.mainLoop(VisorConsole.scala:237)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole$.delayedEndpoint$org$apache$ignite$visor$commands$VisorConsole$1(VisorConsole.scala:358)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole$delayedInit$body.apply(VisorConsole.scala:347)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole$.main(VisorConsole.scala:347)
        at org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole.main(VisorConsole.scala)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1990)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1331)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2141)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1787)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1172)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:668)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:590)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:328)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, addressFilter=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=org.apache.ignite.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@4912d525], reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, soLinger=0,
 forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null, skipAddrsRandomization=false]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:281)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:980)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1985)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to connect to cluster, connection failed and failed to reconnect.
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$Reconnector.body(ClientImpl.java:1711)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:58)
[WARN ] Invalid command name: 'open'
[WARN ] Type 'help' to print commands list.
visor>
```

Comment: Is the visor running on the same POD nearby the server? Or it's a different POD? Replacing the visor with Ignite thick client does work?

Comment: @AlexandrShapkin the visor is running on the same pod.  I suppose launching a thick client would work as well but this has worked in the past and I saw little need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Okay, but where are your clients deployed to then? I suppose to a separate POD, right? If so, I suppose they are using some kind of K8sIpFinder or something like that. But if it's the same POD deployment, I suppose you should be able to access the GG node using internal addresses, like localhost:47000, shouldn't it?

Comment: Anyway, I suppose it's worth checking your configuration. Also, are you sure that you are not using the server config for the visor but the client's one? Cause in the beginning of your question there is a message about "Using configuration | /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config/igniteServer.xml"

Comment: @AlexandrShapkin yes, /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config/igniteServer.xml was just bad naming on my part. I will try the local host but I am a little confused as to what has changed since the last time this worked.

Comment: Well, in that case, it's weird, If there were no changes either in config or infrastructure. We still lack the config file or the logs, but according to the error, it just can't establish the connection.